# How do I create a page that sends a One Time Password to mobile via sms in odoo?

Tags: javascript, openerp-8

I want to create a website login page in which instead of normal login by "User name" and "Password", I generate an OTP (One Time Password) every time the user tries to login to his website. Once the OTP has been generated I need a free service that could sent that generated OTP to a mobile phone via sms.

```
function sendotp(){
              console.log('HELLO');
                var cCode = $("#cCode").val();
                var mobileNumber = $("#mobNumber").val();
                console.log(mobileNumber)
                console.log(cCode)
                if(cCode == "" || cCode == null || cCode == undefined){
                  console.log("Invalid Country Code");
                  $("#sendError").html("Invalid Country Code");
                  return false;
                }

                if(mobileNumber == "" || mobileNumber == null || mobileNumber == undefined){
                  console.log("Invalid Mobile Number Code");
                  $("#sendError").html("Invalid Mobile Number Code");
                  return false;
                }

                $("#vcCode").val(cCode);
                $("#vNumber").val(mobileNumber);
                $(".vNum").html(mobileNumber);

                $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "/generateOTP",
                  data: {countryCode: cCode, mobileNumber: mobileNumber },
                  dataType: "json",
                  error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    var responseObject = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    console.log(responseObject.response.code);
                    $("#sendError").html(responseObject.response.code).addClass("error");
                  },
                  success: function(data) {
                    $("#vNum").val(mobileNumber);
                    console.log('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@')
                    $("#sendError").html(data.response.code).addClass("success");
                    setTimeout(function(){ $("#resendLink").show(); }, 30000);
                    gotoStep(2);
                  }

                })
                console.log('HELOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO')
              }
```

The rest of my parts are working. The problem is only in the $.ajax part.

Comment: Ya its One time password that i want to create please help me

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Try this: https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/

Comment: i dint get any thing from this link can u explain me in detail.